# How to properly label and configure Kubernetes to use Nvidia GPUs?

Tags: kubernetes, gpu, nvidia

I have an in house K8s cluster running on bare metal. On one of my worker nodes I have 4 GPUs and I want to configure K8s to recognise and use these GPUs.
Based on the official documentation I installed all the required stuff and now when I run:

```
docker run --runtime=nvidia --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi


Tue Nov 12 09:20:20 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.67       Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  On   | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 29%   25C    P8     2W / 250W |      0MiB / 10989MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce RTX 208...  On   | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 29%   25C    P8     1W / 250W |      0MiB / 10989MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce RTX 208...  On   | 00000000:82:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 29%   26C    P8     2W / 250W |      0MiB / 10989MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  GeForce RTX 208...  On   | 00000000:83:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 29%   26C    P8    12W / 250W |      0MiB / 10989MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I know that I have to label the node so K8s recognise these GPUs but I can't find the correct labels on the official documentations. On the docs I just see this:

```
# Label your nodes with the accelerator type they have.
kubectl label nodes <node-with-k80> accelerator=nvidia-tesla-k80
```

While on another tutorial (just for google cloude) I found this:

```
aliyun.accelerator/nvidia_count=1                          #This field is important.
aliyun.accelerator/nvidia_mem=12209MiB
aliyun.accelerator/nvidia_name=Tesla-M40
```

So what is the proper way to label my node? Do I need to also label it with the number and memory size of GPUs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are trying to make sure that your pod gets scheduled on a node with GPUs

The easiest way to do it would be to label a node with GPU like this:

```
kubectl label node <node_name> has_gpu=true
```

and then creating your pod add `nodeSelector` fied with `has_gpu: true`. In this way pod will be scheduled only on nodes with GPUs. Read more [here in k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector)

The only problem with it is that in this case scheduler is not aware of how many GPUs are on the node and can schedule more than 4 pods on the node with only 4 GPUs.

Better option would be to use [node extended resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/extended-resource-node/)

It would look like follows:

1. run `kubectl proxy`
2. [patch node resource configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/extended-resource-node/#advertise-a-new-extended-resource-on-one-of-your-nodes):

   ```
   curl --header "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" \
   --request PATCH \
   --data '[{"op": "add", "path": "/status/capacity/example.com~1gpu", "value": "4"}]' \
   http://localhost:8001/api/v1/nodes/<your-node-name>/status
   ```
3. [assign an extender resource to a pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/extended-resource/#assign-an-extended-resource-to-a-pod)

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Pod
   metadata:
   name: extended-resource-demo
   spec:
   containers:
   - name: extended-resource-demo-ctr
       image: my_pod_name
       resources:
           requests:
               example.com/gpu: 1
           limits:
               example.com/gpu: 1
   ```

In this case scheduler is aware how many GPUs are available on the node and won't schedule more pods if cannot satisfy requests.